# Convert Erlang UTF-8 encoded string to java.lang.String

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, erlang, jinterface

The Java node receives an Erlang string encoded in UTF-8. Its class type is `OtpErlangString`. If I simply do `.toString()` or `.stringValue()` the resulting `java.lang.String` has invalid codepoints (basically every byte from the Erlang string is considered distinct character).

Now, I want to use `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` when creating the Java String but how to get the bytes from the `OtpErlangString`?

Comment: Does java.io.StringReader help?

Comment: I don't see how. Can you suggest a way to use it?

Comment: my mistake I thought OtpErlangString extends String.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but there is encode() method which writes to OtpOutputstream which extends ByteArrayOutputStream. This ByteArrayOutputStream has toString method, probably you can use this method.

Comment: `encode()` is used to convert the string to the equivalent Erlang external representation. I don't I should use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange you get OtpErlangString on Java side when you use UTF8 characters. I get object of this type if I use ASCII characters only. If I add at least one UTF8 character, the resulting type is OtpErlangList (which is logical as strings are just lists of ints in Erlang) and then I can use its stringValue() method. So that after sending string form Erlang like:

```
(waco@host)8> {proc, java1@host} ! "ąćśźżęółńa".
[261,263,347,378,380,281,243,322,324,97]
```

On Java node I receive and print it with:

```
OtpErlangList l = (OtpErlangList) mbox.receive();
System.out.println(l.stringValue());
```

The output is correct:

```
ąćśźżęółńa
```

However, if its not the case in your situation, you could try to work it around by forcing OtpErlangList representation by e.g. adding an empty tuple as the very first element of the string list:

```
(waco@wborowiec)11> {proc, java1@wborowiec} ! [{}] ++ "ąćśźżęółńa".
[{},261,263,347,378,380,281,243,322,324,97]
```

And on Java side something like:

```
OtpErlangList l = (OtpErlangList) mbox.receive();
// get rid of an extra tuple
OtpErlangObject[] strArr = Arrays.copyOfRange(l.elements(), 1, l.elements().length);
OtpErlangList l2 = new OtpErlangList(strArr);
System.out.println(l2.stringValue());
```

Comment: Sending [208, 180, 208, 176] which is "да" ("yes" in Russian) results in a `OtpErlangString`. To include an empty tuple in front of the list to force the creation of `OtpErlangList` object is great but aren't there an easier solution? Isn't there a way to extract binary array from `OtpErlangString` object?